# reading CSV file in C and creating an matrix

Tags: arrays, c, csv, file, matrix

I have tried to write a code for reading my CSV file and put the data in a 2D array. but when I run this code I see that all element of array are zero, kindly please help me to know what should I change?

```
int main(void){
    int rowID = 0;  //declare row index
    int columnID = 0;  //declare column index
    int data_new[10000][5] = {{0, 0}};  //create the matrix that we want to put the data
    char line[50000];                  //size of array line
    char token = NULL;
    FILE *data_csv = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    if (data_csv == NULL){
        perror("unable to open the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(line, 50000, data_csv))
    {
        columnID = 0;
        rowID++;

        if (rowID == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }  //to remove the headers
        char *each_line = strtok(line, ", "); //this split the data by ,

         each_line = strtok(NULL, ", ");
         columnID++;
    }
    fclose(data_csv); // Close the file
    for (int i = 0; i < rowID; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        printf("%10.4lf", data_new[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: You never put anything into `data_new` after reading the file, but then you try to print the contents of `data_new`.

Comment: `data_new` is `int` but you try to print it with `"%10.4lf"`. Do you want integer or floating point numbers?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  To start, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  `stdio.h` `string.h` `stdlib.h`

Comment: regarding: `char token = NULL;` You cannot assign a pointer `NULL` to a char

Comment: regarding: `printf("%10.4lf", data_new[i][j]);`  the format specifier is for a `double` but the data is an `int`

Comment: regarding:`int data_new[10000][5] = {{0, 0}};`  since you are trying to store (per a much later call to `printf()` a bunch of `double` values, the type for this data should be `double` not `int` and this is allowing for 10000 rows, each containing 5 `double` values